# How autowire a repository in an integration test with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, repository, autowired

I'm trying to write an integration test but I'm having trouble with autowiring the repository in the test.

I receive this exception:
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.observer.media.repository.ArticleRepository]: Specified class is an interface.

Edit:
I added PersistenceConfig.class with @EnableJpaRepositories, code below. This results in Exception  `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available`

I also tried to add Application.class in @SpringBootTest(classes = {} in an catch all attempt but that throws `Error creating bean with name 'articleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.observer.media.model.Article`

ScraperRunnerIntegrationTest (the config classes only contain beans of domain classes):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        ApplicationConfig.class,
        PersistenceConfig.class,
        DeMorgenTestConfig.class,
        Article.class,
        ScraperRunner.class,
        DeMorgenWebsiteScraper.class,
        ArticleService.class,
        DeMorgenPageScraper.class,
        JsoupParser.class,
        DeMorgenArticleScraper.class,
        GenericArticleScraper.class,
        ImageMetaScraper.class,
        ArticlePrinter.class,
        ArticleRepository.class
})
public class ScraperRunnerIntegrationTest {

    private final static Article EXPECTED_ARTICLE_1 = anArticle().withHeadline("headline1").build();
    private final static Article EXPECTED_ARTICLE_2 = anArticle().withHeadline("headline2").build();

    @Autowired
    private ScraperRunner scraperRunner;
    @Autowired
    private DeMorgenWebsiteScraper deMorgenWebsiteScraper;

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Test
    public void run() {
        scraperRunner.run(deMorgenWebsiteScraper);

        assertThat(articleRepository.findAll()).containsOnly(EXPECTED_ARTICLE_1, EXPECTED_ARTICLE_2);
    }
```

Repository:

```
import org.observer.media.model.Article;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> {

    List<Article> findAll();

    Article findByHash(String hash);

    Article findByHeadline(String headline);

    List<Article> findArticleByHeadlineAndCompanyName(String headline, String companyName);

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(a) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM Article a WHERE a.hash = :hash")
    boolean existsByHash(@Param("hash") String hash);
}
```

PersistenceConfig.class:

```
package org.observer.media.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.observer.media.repository") 
public class PersistenceConfig {
}
```

Comment: do you have `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation  in your `@Configuration` class?

Comment: In this code it's not defined explicitly. I have tried that annotation though and concluded at that moment that it wasn't the culprit and figured that the annotation was included in the SpringBootTest annotation. I might be wrong about that though and will put the annotation back when I have the code in front of me later on. I believe it then complained about not having an EntityManagerFactory which should have been auto configured by Spring Boot I think. Then I provided a config with datasource and emf etc. and then it came back to the same error as in this post.

Comment: @mp_loki I added the annotation EnableJpaRepositories, see my edit in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide only the classes, annotated as `@Configuration` to `@SpringBootTest`.

I have modified the original example from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
So the following configuration works:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("hello")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Note the `@ComponentScan` annotation.
And then in my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={AppConfig.class})
public class CustomerRepositoryTests {
     @Autowired
     private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
}
```

And it did a trick. You can try to do the same in your example.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that throws Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'propertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration]

Comment: there is something messed up with your configuration, and without seeing it all I cannot reason about what exactly. I would suggest you try with as simple configuration as possible and then start adding things one-by-one. Or post your project to GitHub (if it is possible and does not violate any NDAs) and share a link here.

Comment: With SpringBootTest alone, without the classes{...} works: it loads the complete applicationContext, repositories included. When using the classes{}, only a small part of the context is loaded, which is more lean, but the repositories don't come through. That brought up a new problem: autowire testdependencies in beans for an integrationtest. Now it autowires everything together as if it where a normal run. I tried profiles which didn't work but that's another question. I have a factory in place now that creates the test dependency because I can't deal with Spring anymore for today :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception *org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...]: Specified class is an interface* on my integration test. 
I had resolved without using a PersistenceConfig.class but changed only the annotaion used in my integration class that was wrong. I have used the following annotation: 
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
because I didn't want use a in-memory database.

Your code could be the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.observer"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class ScraperRunnerIntegrationTest {

    private final static Article EXPECTED_ARTICLE_1 = anArticle().withHeadline("headline1").build();
    private final static Article EXPECTED_ARTICLE_2 = anArticle().withHeadline("headline2").build();

    @Autowired
    private ScraperRunner scraperRunner;
    @Autowired
    private DeMorgenWebsiteScraper deMorgenWebsiteScraper;

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Test
    public void run() {
        scraperRunner.run(deMorgenWebsiteScraper);

        assertThat(articleRepository.findAll()).containsOnly(EXPECTED_ARTICLE_1, EXPECTED_ARTICLE_2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `@AutoConfigureDataJpa` or `@AutoConfigureXxx` annotations.