# NullPointer Error when trying to use method in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Hello I'm new into Junit and I'm currently coding a unit test using Junit 5 for this class:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + email));

        return user.map(UserDetailsImpl::new).get();
    }
}
```

Below is a test class:

```
class UserDetailsServiceImplTest {

    private static UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    String email;
    /*User mockedUser;
    UserRepository userRepository;
    UserDetails userDetails;*/

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        userDetailsServiceImpl = new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Test
    void testLoadUserByUsername() {
        /*userRepository = mock(UserRepository.class);
        mockedUser = mock(User.class);

        Optional<User> user = Optional.of(mockedUser);

        when(userRepository.findByEmail(email)).thenReturn(user);
        assertEquals(userRepository.findByEmail(email), user);*/

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(email);
        assertTrue(userDetails instanceof UserDetails);
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.108 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.kanban.UserDetailsServiceImplTest
        [ERROR] testLoadUserByUsername  Time elapsed: 0.111 s  <<< ERROR!
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kanban.UserDetailsServiceImplTest.testLoadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImplTest.java:55)

```
    [INFO] Running com.example.kanban.WebSecurityConfigTest
    [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.example.kanban.WebSecurityConfigTest
    2020-04-18 13:36:56.910  INFO 9180 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2020-04-18 13:36:56.910  INFO 9180 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2020-04-18 13:36:56.918  INFO 9180 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2020-04-18 13:36:56.934  INFO 9180 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO]
    [ERROR] Errors:
    [ERROR]   UserDetailsServiceImplTest.testLoadUserByUsername:55 » NullPointer
    [INFO]
    [ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  8.708 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-18T13:36:57+02:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project kanban: There are test failures.
```

I was trying to make `userRepository.findByEmail(email)` method return `Optional<User> user` to make error perish (my attempts are commented out), but I can't deal with this problem.

Comment: I can not see where you have an error exactly but you probably could not autowired userRepository well. Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470877/how-autowire-a-repository-in-an-integration-test-with-spring-boot

Comment: Are you sure the `userRepository` is being autowired? Can you also provide more of your stack trace?

Comment: You need at least 
`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {....})`
did you use these annotations on your test class?

Comment: @Shoshi I've added these annotations, and I still get same error

Comment: @Ascalonian When I run application it works fine, so I'm sure userRepository is being autowired

Comment: @ddoh, add every class that needs spring-context, like bean, configuration, component, in `@SpringBootTest(classes = {....})`.  in this case `@SpringBootTest(classes = {UserDetailsServiceImpl.class})`. if `UserDetailsServiceImpl` use any beans or service or config class, add them too. And try to declare it as `@Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;` and also now you don't need the `setup` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the instance of `UserDetailsServiceImpl` yourself and don't let Spring do it - nothing will be injected. That's what you are doing in the `@BeforeAll`  method because you are using field based injection you don't see that.

If you want to keep using this method of injection you need to let spring inject in your test the `UserDetailsServiceImpl`.

To do so you need to add `@SpringBootTest` to you test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserDetailsServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
}
```

But it seems that you want to mock the UserRespository (and for unit testing it's the best choice) to do so the easiest and clean wait to do it is to update how you do inject and use constructor injection (more on this in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators))

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository
    }
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + email));

        return user.map(UserDetailsImpl::new).get();
    }
}
```

and change your test like a simple unit test:

```
class UserDetailsServiceImplTest {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        userRepository = mock(UserRepository.class)
        userDetailsServiceImpl = new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    void testLoadUserByUsername() {
        mockedUser = mock(User.class);

        Optional<User> user = Optional.of(mockedUser);

        when(userRepository.findByEmail(email)).thenReturn(user);
        assertEquals(userRepository.findByEmail(email), user);

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(email);
        assertTrue(userDetails instanceof UserDetails);
    }
}
```

Just like @bhdrkn suggested you need to read more about the framework and dependency injection in general. And also about unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

`UserRepository` in `UserDetailsServiceImpl` does not get autowired/injected in a unit test because there is no spring context initialised. You can test this kind of dependency using mocks. You can check mockito for that. Alternatively, you can try to initialise Spring Context for tests as well but I don't suggest that.

Beside my answer I have couple of suggestion to you as well:

1. Know your frameworks by heart. They are not just *magic*. Understand how spring works and what Autowired annotation work under the hood.
2. If you are new to dependency injection, I highly recommend [this blog post](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) which explains the basics.
3. You already got some comments which hints you the solution. I believe they are trying to help you by not just providing an answer but instead helping you to find the problem yourself.
4. If you need an example where Spring Boot project unit tested with mockito, you can check [this repository](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Java-Examples/tree/master/jdk8-async-mvc).

I hope this helps.